# How to measure cytochrome P450 activity in owls?

Tags: biochemistry, metabolism, toxicology

I hope you're all doing well. I'm currently working on a research project focused on owls and their exposure to anticoagulation rodenticides such as brodifacoum. As part of my study, I need to measure cytochrome P450 enzymes activity in these birds to assess their ability to metabolize these toxins.

I'm curious to know if there are assay kits or ELISA kits commonly used for measuring cytochrome P450 activity in owls. Any insights or advice would be greatly appreciated. If there are alternative methods or techniques that may be useful in this context, I am open to exploring them as well.

Thank you in advance for your help, and I look forward to any insights you can provide.